# How can I let spring+cometd support webscoket?

Tags: spring, websocket, cometd

I use chrome, it always return:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://192.168.1.228:9090/achat/cometd' failed: Unexpected response code: 400
```

After this error, it use long-polling transport, and success to connect to the server.

How can I let WebSocket work? Is it caused by using SpringFramework 3.1? Thanks.

**Web.xml**

```
<!-- Filter to support cross domain requests -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter</filter-class>
    <!--async-supported>true</async-supported-->
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/cometd/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<!-- Cometd Servlet -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>cometd</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.cometd.annotation.AnnotationCometdServlet</servlet-class>
    <!--async-supported>true</async-supported-->
    <init-param>
        <param-name>timeout</param-name>
        <param-value>20000</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>interval</param-name>
        <param-value>0</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>maxInterval</param-name>
        <param-value>10000</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>maxLazyTimeout</param-name>
        <param-value>5000</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>long-polling.multiSessionInterval</param-name>
        <param-value>2000</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>logLevel</param-name>
        <param-value>100</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>transports</param-name>
        <param-value>org.cometd.websocket.server.WebSocketTransport</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>cometd</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/cometd/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**Servlet**

```
@Named
@Singleton
@Service
public class ChatService {
    @Inject
    private BayeuxServer bayeux;
    @Session
    private ServerSession serverSession;

    @Listener("/chat")
    public void processHello(ServerSession remote, ServerMessage.Mutable message)
    {
        Map<String, Object> input = message.getDataAsMap();
        String room = input.get("room").toString();
        String content = input.get("content").toString();

        Map<String, Object> output = input;        
        bayeux.getChannel("/room/" + room).publish(remote, output, null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow the [CometD Reference Manual](http://docs.cometd.org/reference/), specifically the section that explains how to integrate [CometD with Spring](http://docs.cometd.org/reference/#java_server_services_integration_spring).

There you can find an example that uses Spring's XML configuration to setup WebSocket, and an example of how to configure Spring via annotations.

Your question lacks the Spring configuration file and part of the `web.xml` file so it is difficult to help you in a more detailed way.

Just remember that if you configure CometD in Spring, then you must remove all the CometD configuration from `web.xml`. You must have only one place where you configure things: either `web.xml` or Spring's XML/annotations.